# Jquery JCrop functionality on fluid images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jcrop

So I have implemented JCrop on my image and now there has to be a design change, into making that image fluid.

My image has now `max-height:100%;max-width:100%` and it scales accordingly without JCrop, but with JCrop it doesn't and that is because JCrop sets a fixed witdth and height to the image on intialization, eg:

```
display: none; visibility: hidden; width:540px; height:430px;

$('#feature').children('img').eq(0).removeAttr('style');
$('#feature').children('img').attr('style','display: none; visibility: hidden; width:100% !important;height:100% !important;');
```

But with no avail, it just breaks JCrop.

All I need is to make the image and Jcrop itself adjust and maintain proportions on window resize.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

JSFIDDLE -> http://jsfiddle.net/EHQKH/2/

Just erase the javascript and you should see it resize on window/frame resize, with Jcrop it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

i have a look at this - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHQKH/11/)

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

i removed the style from the img and added it in css

Comment: i hope this is what you were looking for @Gabriel

Comment: It still doesn't resize, drag the frame holder in jsfiddle on the frame that holds the image and you should see that the image doesn't resize, instead the scrollbars appear. Delete the javascript and the css and resize the frame, you should be able to see the image being scaled with max-width and max-height. Thanks!

Comment: maybe this will be able to help - http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=advanced