# How to get responsive images working with JCrop

Tags: jcrop

I see some solutions where the truesize property is used to get JCrop to work with responsive images correctly. However, I'm having a hard time getting the images responsive in the first place when using JCrop. If I remove the jCrop code and add the following css, the image is responsive.

In short - JCrop works. Responsive image works. But when put together, the image isn't responsive.

JSFiddle here: Just uncomment the css.
http://jsfiddle.net/work77/oh5esg19/

```
img{
max-width:80%;
max-height:80%;
}
```

Very similar question is unanswered here:
[Jquery JCrop functionality on fluid images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815415/jquery-jcrop-functionality-on-fluid-images)

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
img {
    max-width:80%;
    height:auto;
}
.jcrop-holder img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Mattias, I tried your code in the fiddle above and sadly the image is still not responsive. Did you try it, and maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: No, you are absolutely right, it's not responsive. Friday afternoon :-(. But it  loads the image in the correct size for the viewport at load time. But that was of course not the question. Maybe with some javascript trickery on window resize events? I'm trying to find a solution myself...

Comment: "But it loads the image in the correct size for the viewport at load time." Good point here. I didn't really notice that. This way might work for me too. Thanks.

Comment: @JimSmith Hi Jim, would like to know did you solve the responsiveness of Jcrop images

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting the max width with css you can limit it with jcrop.

```
$('#cropbox').Jcrop({
    aspectRatio: 1,
    boxWidth: 450,   //Maximum width you want for your bigger images
    boxHeight: 400,  //Maximum Height for your bigger images
    onSelect: updateCoords,
});
```

Setting boxWidth and boxHeight will set the size of your box and the image inside will keep its propotions.